# Angular2 Routing 3.0.0x Get Errors for style.css when using parameters

Tags: parameters, angular, routes

I'm in Angular2 with the latest Router package (3.0.0.8?)

When I add a parameter to one of my routes, the page can no longer find all the necessary style and app files.

When I have this:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', component: LandingPageComponent },
    { path: 'buyers', component: BuyerFormComponent },
    {path: 'links', component: GenerateLinksComponent},
    {path: 'cc/:bid', component: SupplierFormComponent}
];
```

When I navigate to "http://localhost:3000/cc/b4"
I get a bunch of errors:

> GET http://localhost:3000/cc/styles.css 
>   GET http://localhost:3000/cc/app etc

My other routes without parameters work fine and if I remove the parameter from the route:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', component: LandingPageComponent },
    { path: 'buyers', component: BuyerFormComponent },
    {path: 'links', component: GenerateLinksComponent},
    {path: 'cc', component: SupplierFormComponent}
];
```

And visit the route without a parameter (localhost3000/cc), the page loads fine.

I have the href="." in my index.html as such:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <base href=".">
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new router requires

```
<base href="/">
```

Empty path routes usually should have set `terminal: true`

```
{path: '', component: LandingPageComponent, terminal: true },
```

In beta.9 `terminal: true` will be replaced by

```
{path: '', component: LandingPageComponent, pathMatch: full },
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/router/src/config.ts#L258

Comment: This fixed it, thank you! (apparently I can't accept the answer for 8 minutes...)

Comment: I was using what I think is the latest guide: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href and it still calls for '.' Is there a more recent guide and can you point me to documentation regarding  'terminal: true'? Thank you again.

Comment: It was mentioned in GitHub issues that this needs to be updated. For `terminal` check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html I saw some more extensive explanation recently but don't recall where. It basically says that it should only match when the whole path is `''`, otherwise it would match for prefix `'''` which would be every route. `terminal` is deprecated though. I'll update the answer.